# Linear Hypothesis for a quantile regression in r

Tags: r, quantile-regression

I would like to test a linear hypothesis in a median regression model similar to example below.

```
require(AER);require(car);require(quantreg)
data("CPS1985")

#Regular linear model
model.lm <- lm(wage ~ ethnicity + age*gender,CPS1985)
summary(model.lm)
linearHypothesis(model.lm,"age + age:genderfemale = 0")

#Quantile regression
model.quant <- rq(wage ~ ethnicity + age*gender,tau=0.5,data=CPS1985)
```

I'm not sure, however, how to execute a linear Hypothesis for `model.quant` to test that the sum of the coefficients on age and age:gender are equal to zero.

Comment: Note: The proper test is usually not that the sum of the coefficients is zero; it is that both coefficients are zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require(rms)
f <- Rq(wage ~ ethnicity + age * gender, tau=.5, data=...)
anova(f)  # provides test of age + age*gender
print(anova(f), which='dots')  # show which coefficients are tested
f <- Rq(wage ~ ethnicity + rcs(age,4) * gender, tau=.5, ...)
anova(f)  # more general test with regression spline for age

g <- orm(wage ~ ethnicity + rcs(age, 4) * gender, ...)
anova(g)  # More powerful tests using ordinal regression
          # orm by default uses proportional odds model
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't aware of the rms package