# Joint hypothesis test for quantile regression in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, quantile-regression

I am new to quantile regression and, currently, I am reading a paper that reports results of an F-test for a linear median (quantile) regression. The model is easy and a minimal working example in R would be as follows:

```
## generate some data
s <- rbeta( 100, 0.6, 2 )
x <- rbeta( 100, 2, 5 )
data <- as.data.frame( cbind( s, x ) )

## linear median regression
require(rms)
quant.model <- Rq( s ~ x, tau = 0.5, data = data )
```

Apparently, the F-test reported in that paper tests the joint hypothesis that the estimated coefficient of the intercept is zero and the estimated coefficient of x is 1 ($\beta_0 = 0$, $\beta_1 = 1$). And this is where I am stuck. I have no idea how I would set up such a test in R (as `linearHypothesis()` does not work with quantile regressions).

I have scoured the internet to the best of my capabilities and found [this helpful post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71001/linear-hypothesis-for-a-quantile-regression-in-r), which uses the `anova` function from the `rms` package I believe. However, the joint test in that post only tests for a combination of coefficients to be jointly zero.

For now, I have no idea how to set up a test for the joint hypothesis $H_0$: $\beta_0 = 0$, $\beta_1 = 1$. Could you point me in the right direction, please?

Cheerio!

Comment: It's a while since I did a quantile regression, but - assuming the test you mention is correct - if there's not already an *offset* argument in the function you call above to fit the model (which should work), wouldn't regressing s-x on x and testing both coefficients being zero work?

Comment: Thank you Glen_b, I never thought about that and it seems to work fine. However, using the anova way described in the linked post above provides chi_sq statistics. Unfortunately, I really need to work with the F-statistic (for specific reasons that I cannot change). After some more unsuccessful digging, I will just calculate the F-test manually. I'll post an answer about how in a bit.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but why would the statistic have an F distribution?

Comment: Glen, I have actually trouble answering your question. All I am trying to do is to replicate an analysis from another paper. In fact, I am very much confused about why and how these guys use and F-test for joint hypothesis testing in a quantile regression.

Comment: I can see getting tests that are asymptotically normal (for say a coefficient) and potentially chi-squared (for say an overall test of a null model vs full model, or perhaps some linear hypothesis), ... but if there was some kind of small-sample F-approximation I would expect it to involve either a scale factor or non-integer degrees of freedom, or quite likely both. Perhaps there's a neat result I'm ignorant of -- that would not surprise me at all (it's a very large category of things), which was why I was asking.

Comment: @Glen_b, I am not afraid to admit that I am quite out of my depth here. Moreover, I have only a vague idea of what the original authors do as I merely rely on reported results. I'd love to have their Stata or R script at hand. I have cited the paper in a comment below. Maybe the original paper (and its online appendix) helps you in finding your neat result. In any case, thanks for joining this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

After some more searching and frustration, I decided to just do the F-test manually (and in a quick and dirty way). Here is how, in case some poor soul will have the same problem at some point in time.

First, I wrote a function to manually calculate an F-test for simple linear regression models.

```
##     manual F-test for linear hypothesis testing
##     requires the unrestricted and the restricted model
manual_LHT <- function(mod_u, mod_r){
  # --- get variables
  #     sum of sqared residuals
  SSR_u <- sum(unname(mod_u$residuals)^2)
  SSR_r <- sum(unname(mod_r$residuals)^2)
  #     number of restrictions (i.e., difference in residual degrees of freedom)
  q <- mod_r$df.residual - mod_u$df.residual
  #     number of regressors in unsrestricted model
  k <- dim(mod_u$model)[2] - 1
  #     number of observations
  n <- length(mod_u$residuals)
  
  # --- calculate F statistic
  nominator <- (SSR_r - SSR_u)/q
  denominator <- SSR_u/(n - k - 1)
  F_val <- nominator/denominator
  
  # --- calcuate p-value
  p_val <- pf(F_val, q, (n - k - 1), lower.tail = FALSE)
  return(list(Fval = F_val, pval = p_val))
}
```

Second, I did a little sanity check using [this standard example](https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/7-3-joint-hypothesis-testing-using-the-f-statistic.html).

```
library(AER)
library(MASS)
data("CASchools")

CASchools$size <- CASchools$students/CASchools$teachers
CASchools$score <- (CASchools$read + CASchools$math)/2
CASchools$expenditure <- CASchools$expenditure/1000

model <- lm(score ~ size + english + expenditure, data = CASchools)
model.restricted <- lm(score ~ english, data = CASchools)

linearHypothesis(model, c("size=0", "expenditure=0"))
manual_LHT(mod_u = model, mod_r = model.restricted)
```

Both `linearHypothesis()` and `manual_LHT()` lead to the same results regarding F-statistic and p-value. Console output for the former:

```
> linearHypothesis(model, c("size=0", "expenditure=0"))
Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis:
size = 0
expenditure = 0

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: score ~ size + english + expenditure

  Res.Df   RSS Df Sum of Sq      F   Pr(>F)    
1    418 89000                                 
2    416 85700  2    3300.3 8.0101 0.000386 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Console output for the latter.

```
> manual_LHT(mod_u = model, mod_r = model.restricted)
$Fval
[1] 8.010125

$pval
[1] 0.0003859748
```

Now, one important thing is to adapt the `manual_LHT()` function to the specifics of the regression model object. Specifically regarding quantile regressions with `quantreg`, the residual degrees of freedom can be obtained from `summary(mod_r)$rdf` instead of `mod_r$df.residual` like it is now in `manual_LHT()`. So, pay attention to this little adaptation requirement.

I am happy for any feedback. Maybe going this way is a big blunder. ;)

Comment: I wonder if the test statistic has an F-distribution under the null hypothesis. I would’ve expected that to be quite reliant on variance/square loss, which are less interesting in a quantile regression (especially if you use a quantile that isn’t the median).

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for this comment. As I mentioned above in a response to Glen_b, I share your skepticism. All I am trying to do is to replicate an analysis from another paper. In fact, I am very much confused about why and how these guys use and F-test for joint hypothesis testing in a quantile regression. So, my question for now is not whether this makes sense, but how one could appropriately retrieve an F-test for quantile regressions.

Comment: Could you please cite the paper? (Citation, not just link, as links can rot)

Comment: @Dave, sorry for responding late. I was on a much needed short vacation, intentionally without any internet access. The paper is: Rodriguez-Lara & Moreno-Garrido (2012), "Self-interest and fairness: self-serving choices of justice principles", Experimental Economics, 15, 158-175, [DOI: 10.1007/s10683-011-9295-3](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10683-011-9295-3)